# Google App Engine Datastore Data Privacy

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, privacy

I'm playing around with the Google App Engine and the Datastore.

Really amazing stuff going on over there.

But I couldn't help and wonder what Google is allowed to do with the data my application is storing in there Datastore.

Can someone explain it in simple worlds?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Google App Engine is governed by Google's [general Privacy Policy](http://www.google.com/intl/en/privacy/privacy-policy.html). They promise not to share information outside of Google except in certain circumstances (court order, etc.), and they restrict access to only employees who need it. However, because they can use your data to "provide, maintain, protect and improve our services," Google may be using your data for their own purposes (probably not, but I see nothing that prevents them).

*Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer. Also, this policy doesn't provide GAE-specific information.*

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that Google Cloud has separate [Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/terms/) that includes this line:

> 5.2 Use of Customer Data. Google will not access or use Customer Data, except as necessary to provide the Services to Customer.