# Does new Google privacy policies affect Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, privacy

I know there is already a familiar question:
[Google App Engine Datastore Data Privacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179144/google-app-engine-datastore-data-privacy)
But the answer of the question above is not clear and the time of the answer is at middle of 2011.

But recently, on March, Google has changed their policies. Now I want to know exactly whether they will use the information in my data store.

Answer (score 1):

App Engine is governed by the App Engine Terms of Service, found [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/terms.html). In particular, check out section 6.1, regarding Intellectual Property Rights.

Comment: Sorry but I am not lawyer, I can't understand what that mean. For example, If my datastore has data of my customer, will Google have rights to use the data as they want?

Comment: @user477768 I cannot offer legal advice. If you're unsure of the meaning of the Terms Of Service, you should seek advice from a lawyer.